# Can read post data from php submitted to classic asp for processing data?

Tags: php, post, asp-classic

I would like to design interface for PHP page, for example a drop down list of months for user to select, and then post this data to another page (classic ASP page) for processing the data to query search all customer sales order in that selected month.

Currently I force my page displayed from the another page in asp, for example:

```
"myexample.com/order.asp?month=".date('Y-m')
```

After I implement my drop-down list in PHP, for example:

```
<select>
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
  <option>March</option>
</select>
```

Can I write the above url in my form's **action** ?

```
method="POST" action="myexample.com/order.asp?"
```

And, in my asp page, request string from url?

```
Dim month = Request.Form("month")
```

Please kindly advise me, the formatting for using asp to process data is fixed to be using in this way, and will get the data result into array and pass back to PHP page to draw out table and displaying data.

Comment: Wait, so you're using PHP and ASP on the same server? Why not just one or the other?

Comment: You can post data from PHP to ASP that is possible ,,

Comment: use ajax to retrive the responses

Answer (score 1):

In every web technology is is possible to read post/get parameters So the answer is YES you can read "php post parameters" in asp.

When php/asp.net/asp...  page is parsed it is yust plain old html.

Answer (score 0):

you probably meant:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
  <option>March</option>
</select>
```

not:

```
<select>
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
  <option>March</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on the element you have now, try the following code:

```
<javascript>
function OnSubmitForm()
{
  document.form1.action ="myexample.com/order.asp?month="+document.form1.month.value;
  return true;
}
</javascript>
<form name=form1 method="POST" onsubmit="return onsubmitform();">
<select name="month">
...
```